# Number Theory proof involving Legendre symbol

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Suppose $a,b$ are integers s.t. $ab\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Show $(\frac{a^2+a}{p})=(\frac{b+1}{p})$.

Not really sure on how to approach this proof.

If I take $a^2+a\equiv 0\pmod{p}$

$a\equiv -a^2\pmod{p}$

$b^2a\equiv -b^2a^2\pmod{p}$

$b\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ so $b+1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$

Not sure how to use this or if I'm able to use this to prove the goal.

OR I can say since $a^2+a\in Q_p$

$s^2\equiv a^2+a\pmod{p}$ for some $s\in U_p$ then multiply by $b^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(b^2|p) = (b|p)^2 = 1$,

$$\left(\frac{a^2 + a}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{a^2 + a}{p}\right)\left(\frac{b^2}{p}\right)= \left(\frac{a^2b^2 + ab^2}{p}\right) =\cdots$$

Complete the argument using the condition $ab \equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: $(=\frac{1+b}{p})$. This is probably a silly question but how are you getting $(b^2|p)$?

Comment: That's correct. I used the fact that $(b^2|p) = 1$ (the notation $(a|p)$ I used means $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$).

Comment: All clear now. Thanks.